# Add element to a tuple outside of initialization c#

Tags: c#, tuples

I'm new to programming, and I created a tuple list with

```
var tupleList = new List<Tuple<string, string>> { };
```

Later on in the code, I'd like to add an element like

```
tupleList.Add(string1,string2);
```

but .Add doesn't support this somehow?

Basically, I'm going through a loop and adding to the tuple and later I want to search through the tuple for a sample string, so my second question is how would I search through tupleList.Item1 and get all the pairs that equal, for example string10? I saw an answer for dictionary values, but can I do the same for tuples?

```
var matches = tupleList.Where(pair => pair.Item1.Equals(string10))
                  .Select(pair => Item2.Key);
```

I don't know if that makes sense though, this was the original code:

```
var matches = dict.Where(pair => pair.Value == "abc")
                  .Select(pair => pair.Key);
```

Comment: I rolled back your edit. If you have another problems, then accept current question and ask new one. Don't modify question by adding new problems to it

Comment: Oh, ok, sorry, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`List<T>` does not have any specific methods for working with tuples. It works with any type `T`. If you want to add new item to list, you should create item of list's type `T` and pass it to list. Adding new tuple:

```
tupleList.Add(Tuple.Create(string1,string2));
```

For searching just filter tuples list. You should not project tuples with `Select` operator if you want to get them as result:

```
var matches = tupleList.Where(pair => pair.Item1 == string10);
```

NOTE: I don't like tuples for their meaningless names Item1, Item2 etc, which is hard to understand. Consider creating custom class which will have properties with descriptive names.

Comment: Thanks, adding tuples with your code made the dreaded red squiggly go away. As for the matches, I realized that what I really want is any string that has a match, so instead of doing a foreach and going through every Item1 and seeing if it has a match elsewhere, could I just delete any tuples (with respect to Item1) that don't appear twice or more?

Comment: @user3408097 it's not very clear what you are trying to achieve. You want to select only first tuple which matches given Item1 value?

Comment: Oh, sorry, what I meant was, for example, if I have the following list [(1,2)(1,4)(1,5)(2,3)(4,6)(1,3)(3,7)] I just want to remove (2,3) because 2 only exists once. I want to KEEP the duplicates based on the Item1 value

Comment: @user3408097 still not clear - you have (4,6) and (3,7) which exist only once. Why only (2,3) should be removed?

Comment: Oh, sorry, those should be removed too, I think I was typing too fast and I thought (2,3) was the only one

Comment: But I'll put up another question

Comment: @user3408097 you need to use grouping instead of simple filtering here `tupleList.GroupBy(t => t.Item1).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).SelectMany(g => g)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56493/discussion-between-user3408097-and-sergey-berezovskiy).

Comment: Actually you answered all the questions perfectly, it was just a dumb implementation mistake by me (just got into programming recently).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say why do the same for tuples?

If you are using a tuple to represent a key value pair, just stick to a key value pair, which is what a dictionary contains a collection of.  If you model a row with more than 2 values, I'd probably favour a strongly typed model over this, where you can be more explicit in your LINQ queries.